# I'm trying to access store data (getters) in my middleware router guard but returns false

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I'm creating a new page "`/gettingstarted`" for new users that have not yet created sub-accounts inside our system.
So based on our store data if the user has no accounts I have to redirect them to the "`/gettingstarted`" page every time the user navigates to another page but the problem with it is that every time I refresh the page then "`hasAccounts`" getter is rendered after the page reload which makes sense because thats what router guards are. But I need a way around this to work and make the router guard wait for the getter

**middleware.js**

```
Router.beforeEach(function (to, from, next) {
  if (!store.getters["accounts/hasAccount"]) {
    next({
      path: '/gettingstarted'
    })
  } else {
    next()
  }
})
```

*Here is the getter to fetch true and false*

**store.js**

```
 hasAccount(state) {
      if (state.accounts.data) {
        if (state.accounts.data.length > 0) {
          return true
        } else return false
      } else return false
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reload page will reinitialize vuex.  So `state.accounts.data` should be saved with cookies or localStorage

Comment: I actually stored my `accounts.data` in a local storage  `localStorage.setItem('hasAccount', accounts.data)` and it worked for me. Then I just replaced  `if (!store.getters["accounts/hasAccount"])` in my code with `if(!localStorage.getItem('hasAccount)` and it worked